# Sheaf-theoretic approach to Morse functions?

Tags: sheaf-theory, smooth-manifolds, morse-theory

It is known that one can define a smooth structure on a manifold using a sheaf-theoretic formulation via defining the algebra of the (a fortiori) smooth functions on it (which satisfies the usual equalizer condition), therefore defining the manifold by its maps instead of the regular charts.

I'm wondedring whether one can similarly define a structure sheaf using Morse functions instead.

Clearly, the set of Morse functions on a manifold does not have an algebra structure (or even a group structure) with the usual operations.
So can we still define the necessary group/algebra structure on Morse functions, so that the resulting sheaf would make sense? In this case, will we get some meaningful structure on the manifold?

Comment: What is the benefit of using the Morse functions VS ordinary $C^{\infty}$ functions in this case?

Comment: I'm hoping to get a different/additional (if we already assume a smooth structure) structure, instead of the smooth one. Part of the motivation is combinatorial Morse theory; perhaps such a structure would give some interesting corresponding structure in that case.